# why does not onload() work when i close the tab?

Tags: javascript, html

i wrote this simple function to show a message when you close the window but it didnt work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body onunload="closing()">
  <script language="javascript">
     function closing(){
         alert('Bye');
         
     }
     
    

  </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you look at the debug console and reload your page, you'll see a blocked message briefly appear.

Answer (score -1):

Your popup blocker might block it. [MDN docs source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload)

That sort of behavior - alerts popping up on a close, are usually not desired by users.

Did you try using the `unload` event?